# Use different optimizers depending on a if statement in TENSORFLOW

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, neural-network, initializer, loss

I'm currently trying to implement a neural network with two training steps. First i want to reduce the loss_first_part function and then i want to reduce the loss_second_part.

```
tf.global_variable_initializer().run()

for epoch in range(nb_epochs)
    if epoch < 10 : 
       train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss_first_part)
    else :
       train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss_second_part)
```

**The problem is that the initializer should be defined after the optimizer.minimize call**. Indeed i've the following error `Attempting to use unintialized value betal_power`.

How can i fix this problem considering that i want my optimizer to depend on the epoch...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found ! So simple...

```
train_step1 = optimizer.minimize(loss_first_part)
train_step2 = optimizer.minimize(loss_second_part)
tf.global_variable_initializer().run()

if ... :
   sess.run(train_step1)
else :
   sess.run(train_step2)
```